# Spurious timeout before allowing me to log in or authenticate for sudo

Tags: usb, authentication, syslog, timeout

Soemtimes when I use sudo at the command line, nothing happens for 20+ seconds. After that, the desired things happens, which is that I am told to swipe my finger on the fingerprint reader or, if that doesn't happen, to enter a password.

Similarly, sometimes when the screen is locked and I try to unlock/revive, sometimes it does nothing for about 20+ seconds.

How do I debug this infuriating behaviour? Anyone else seen it?

thanks!

update: Here's an example of syslog during one of these incidents:

```
Apr  7 10:31:21 T450s-high kernel: [1007821.465715] usb 2-7: new full-speed USB device number 95 using xhci_hcd
Apr  7 10:31:21 T450s-high kernel: [1007821.601740] usb 2-7: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Apr  7 10:31:22 T450s-high dbus-daemon[1621]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='net.reactivated.Fprint' unit='fprintd.service' requested by ':1.16814' (uid=0 pid=3682008 comm="sudo emacs /etc/hosts " label="unconfined")
Apr  7 10:31:22 T450s-high systemd[1]: Starting Fingerprint Authentication Daemon...
Apr  7 10:31:35 T450s-high systemd[3073]: Started Application launched by gsd-media-keys.
Apr  7 10:31:35 T450s-high systemd[3073]: Started VTE child process 3682066 launched by gnome-terminal-server process 1924388.
Apr  7 10:31:37 T450s-high kernel: [1007837.313788] usb 2-7: device descriptor read/64, error -110
Apr  7 10:31:37 T450s-high kernel: [1007837.549784] usb 2-7: new full-speed USB device number 96 using xhci_hcd
Apr  7 10:31:37 T450s-high kernel: [1007837.681771] usb 2-7: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Apr  7 10:31:37 T450s-high kernel: [1007837.925788] usb 2-7: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Apr  7 10:31:37 T450s-high kernel: [1007838.033835] usb usb2-port7: attempt power cycle
Apr  7 10:31:38 T450s-high kernel: [1007838.693813] usb 2-7: new full-speed USB device number 97 using xhci_hcd
Apr  7 10:31:38 T450s-high kernel: [1007838.693956] usb 2-7: Device not responding to setup address.
Apr  7 10:31:38 T450s-high kernel: [1007838.901916] usb 2-7: Device not responding to setup address.
Apr  7 10:31:38 T450s-high kernel: [1007839.109764] usb 2-7: device not accepting address 97, error -71
Apr  7 10:31:38 T450s-high kernel: [1007839.241739] usb 2-7: new full-speed USB device number 98 using xhci_hcd
Apr  7 10:31:38 T450s-high kernel: [1007839.241879] usb 2-7: Device not responding to setup address.
Apr  7 10:31:39 T450s-high kernel: [1007839.449901] usb 2-7: Device not responding to setup address.
Apr  7 10:31:39 T450s-high kernel: [1007839.661741] usb 2-7: device not accepting address 98, error -71
Apr  7 10:31:39 T450s-high kernel: [1007839.661817] usb usb2-port7: unable to enumerate USB device
Apr  7 10:31:39 T450s-high dbus-daemon[1621]: [system] Successfully activated service 'net.reactivated.Fprint'
Apr  7 10:31:39 T450s-high systemd[1]: Started Fingerprint Authentication Daemon.
```

And here is kern.log:

```
Apr  7 10:31:01 T450s-high kernel: [1007801.937805] usb usb2-port7: unable to enumerate USB device
Apr  7 10:31:21 T450s-high kernel: [1007821.465715] usb 2-7: new full-speed USB device number 95 using xhci_hcd
Apr  7 10:31:21 T450s-high kernel: [1007821.601740] usb 2-7: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Apr  7 10:31:37 T450s-high kernel: [1007837.313788] usb 2-7: device descriptor read/64, error -110
Apr  7 10:31:37 T450s-high kernel: [1007837.549784] usb 2-7: new full-speed USB device number 96 using xhci_hcd
Apr  7 10:31:37 T450s-high kernel: [1007837.681771] usb 2-7: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Apr  7 10:31:37 T450s-high kernel: [1007837.925788] usb 2-7: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Apr  7 10:31:37 T450s-high kernel: [1007838.033835] usb usb2-port7: attempt power cycle
Apr  7 10:31:38 T450s-high kernel: [1007838.693813] usb 2-7: new full-speed USB device number 97 using xhci_hcd
Apr  7 10:31:38 T450s-high kernel: [1007838.693956] usb 2-7: Device not responding to setup address.
Apr  7 10:31:38 T450s-high kernel: [1007838.901916] usb 2-7: Device not responding to setup address.
Apr  7 10:31:38 T450s-high kernel: [1007839.109764] usb 2-7: device not accepting address 97, error -71
Apr  7 10:31:38 T450s-high kernel: [1007839.241739] usb 2-7: new full-speed USB device number 98 using xhci_hcd
Apr  7 10:31:38 T450s-high kernel: [1007839.241879] usb 2-7: Device not responding to setup address.
Apr  7 10:31:39 T450s-high kernel: [1007839.449901] usb 2-7: Device not responding to setup address.
Apr  7 10:31:39 T450s-high kernel: [1007839.661741] usb 2-7: device not accepting address 98, error -71
Apr  7 10:31:39 T450s-high kernel: [1007839.661817] usb usb2-port7: unable to enumerate USB device
```

The usb errors don't look good. Is this helpful?

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. Integrated Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 030: ID 0bc2:ab34 Seagate RSS LLC Backup Plus
Bus 003 Device 029: ID 17ef:1010 Lenovo ThinkPad Ultra Dock Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 04ca:703c Lite-On Technology Corp. Integrated Camera
Bus 002 Device 123: ID 138a:0017 Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS 5011 fingerprint sensor
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04f3:0418 Elan Microelectronics Corp. Touchscreen
Bus 002 Device 087: ID 047d:1022 Kensington Orbit Optical
Bus 002 Device 086: ID 046d:0826 Logitech, Inc. HD Webcam C525
Bus 002 Device 083: ID 17ef:100f Lenovo ThinkPad Ultra Dock Hub
Bus 002 Device 080: ID 17ef:1010 Lenovo ThinkPad Ultra Dock Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

UPDATE

@Rinzwind may be helping me solve an unrelated problem (USB). Related to that, I'm listing the contents of my /etc/modprobe.d:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   41 Jun 30  2021 blacklist-oss.conf -> /lib/linux-sound-base/noOSS.modprobe.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2733 Mar 30  2020 alsa-base.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1518 Apr 12  2019 blacklist.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  677 Apr 12  2019 blacklist-framebuffer.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  154 Aug 24  2018 intel-microcode-blacklist.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  154 Jun 26  2018 amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  325 May 28  2018 blacklist-ath_pci.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  210 May 28  2018 blacklist-firewire.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  583 May 28  2018 blacklist-rare-network.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  347 May 28  2018 iwlwifi.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  127 Feb  7  2017 dkms.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2507 Jul 30  2015 alsa-base.conf~
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  156 Jul 30  2015 blacklist-modem.conf
```

There is no "options:" file. Should I create it?

As for the possibilty of domain name resolution being the problem, how can I tell? I'm on a major University campus connected by ethernet but maybe something to do with my own hostname could be the problem?

Comment: Check the newest altered file in /var/log/ (`sudo ls -ltr /var/log/`) when it happens and use tail to view the last few lines (`sudo tail -n 25 /var/log/{filename}`). Check for errors and if there are any google those.

Comment: I've seen something *like* this related to a hostname resolution problem I think?

Comment: @Rinzwind  Thank you. I did that. It's Greek to me.

Comment: Please see if my answer fixes the errors in your logs. I do realize it might not be an answer to the long delay though. I agree with steeldriver: long delays can be related to hostname resolution. Might want to investigate that too.

Answer (score 0):

This answers the errors in the logs and might not be the answer to the problem so if this is not it please PM me and I will remove it.

The `device descriptor read/64, error -110` might be cause by the `-71`.
Regarding the `device descriptor read/64, error -71`. That error might be the cause of the long delay.

Alter file

```
 /etc/modprobe.d/options:
```

and add

```
options usbcore use_both_schemes=y
```

Reboot is probably needed.

[Source](https://www.spinics.net/lists/usb/msg02644.html) and the explanation:

> The "old scheme" is the way Linux worked before 2.6.10.  When a new
> device is plugged in, the system first assigns it an address, then
> reads the initial 8 bytes of the device descriptor, then reads the
> entire 18-byte device descriptor.
>
> The "new scheme" is basically the way Windows works.  (Not
> surprisingly, some devices won't work any other way.)  When a new
> device is plugged in, the system first issues a 64-byte read request
> for the device descriptor, then resets the device, then assigns it an
> address, and then reads the  actual 18-byte device descriptor.
>
> The reason for these shenanigans is that with a full-speed device, the
> maximum packet size for endpoint 0 (ep0maxpacket) isn't known
> beforehand.   It could be 8, 16, 32, or 64 bytes.  (Low-speed devices
> must use 8, and high-speed devices must use 64.)  The ep0maxpacket
> value is stored in the initial 8 bytes of the device descriptor, but
> to read the device descriptor you have to use endpoint 0!
>
> The two schemes above are the two common solutions to this
> chicken-and-egg problem.  The old scheme is the one recommended by the
> USB Implementors Forum (which makes it the "Standard"); the new scheme
> is the one used by Microsoft (which makes it another kind of
> "Standard"!).  A well-designed standards-compliant device will work
> okay with either scheme.   Unfortunately it seems that no matter which
> scheme you pick, some badly-designed non-compliant devices won't work.
> There's an additional usbcore.ko module parameter people can use in
> especially bad cases:
>
> ```
> use_both_schemes=y
> ```
>
> This will cause the system to try one of the schemes, and if it fails
> then  try the other scheme.  (Maybe that should always be the
> default...)